# Unknown column 'r' in field list

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been working on a SQL query for a project, and I face an error message when I want to use it.

Here is the query itself :

```
SELECT  COUNT(r)                                AS  auditMade,
        SUM(g.nbrMilkingCows)                   AS  cowsAudited,
        AVG(r.gainPerCowPerYearTransition)      AS  averageGainTransition,
        AVG(r.gainPerCowPerYearLactation)       AS  averageGainLactation,
        AVG(r.totalGain)                        AS  averageTotalGain,
        AVG(r.supplementalCostPerCow)           AS  averageSuppCost
FROM        `smart_calculator_infos` i
INNER JOIN  `smart_calculator_result` r             ON  r.idSmartCalculatorResult = i.idSmartCalculatorResult
INNER JOIN  `calculator_general_informations` g     ON  g.idSmartCalculatorInfo = i.idSmartCalculatorInfo
WHERE   i.idUser = 14
```

MySQL answers me "Unknown column 'r' in field list".

But I dont really understand why I get an error here as I define r in my INNER JOIN.

I'm kinda new at using SQL so maybe there is something pretty obvious I forgot, but I can't seem to understand what.

Comment: Inside `COUNT()` you must use a column's name or `*` and not a table's name or alias.

Comment: Hi @Eindall: Use 1 or r.* or r.column_name inside COUNT()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't count an alias itself, so the very first line of your query is what is causing the error:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(r)
```

To remedy this, you could use `COUNT(*)`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
```

Or, you could count an actual column in the `smart_calculator_result` table, e.g.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(r.idSmartCalculatorResult)
```

Comment: @Eindall Happy to help you, and you can _count_ on my answer being generally correct `:-P`